# Vertex group is not moved by bone (only overlapping vertices seem to move)

Tags: animation, bones, vertex-groups, actions

I have bones for the forefoot (Element.005) and the heel (Element.006) of a foot:

[image]

I have painted weights for both:

[image]
[image]

Moving the of the forefoot deforms the mesh as intended. However, the other bone does not move the heel. Only vertices that appear to be overlapping with the vertex group Element.005 (forefoot) appear to be moving. The heel stays where it is.

Can somebody explain why this is the case?
Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: enable the Deform option of this bone. If it is not the problem, please share your file

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to find the issue. I post the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the armature modifier of the mesh had the vertex group Element.005 selected. Therefore, Element.006 only moved the vertices of that group. Removing the vertex group solved the problem.

[image]